# FX exposure in foreign equity index futures and commodity futures

Tags: futures, fx, exposure

For an US investor, buying an European index futures contract doesn't generate EURUSD exposure to the portfolio, since this trade is equivalent to borrowing EUR and buying the underlying.

Can I follow that same reasoning for commodity futures priced in EUR, for example carbon trading? Does trading it entail any FX exposure?

Comment: I am not familiar with carbon trading. But as long as you hold the commodity future in a US futures account (collateralized wih USD assets) it would seem that opening the position does not create any EUR exposure. (But note that as the trade unfolds, the P&L will create a positive or negative EUR position in the account and thus a (small) exposure. Only on the P&L to date, not on the notional. From time to time you can convert those EUR to USD to minimize this).

Comment: So the only way you can get FX exposure on the notional by trading futures is trading currency futures, I guess?

Comment: I guess that's what those fx futures are for, right ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very interesting

Yes id say same logic applies to a euro commodity futures.

the futures is like a series of 1 day forward contracts, so any day, your fx exposure is only on that days euro gains/losses